# .cdk-drag-preview not applying styles

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using the cdk Drag and Drop from angular material, but the drag preview is not working as intended.. I want the preview to look exactly like the element being dragged, but the preview is only showing the text content of the element (no styles).

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields$ | async" class="fields-list-container" cdkDrag cdkDragLockAxis="y">
            <div class="fields-name-desc-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
                <div>
                    <div>{{field.name}}</div>
                    <div><em>{{field.displayType | titlecase }}</em>( )</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                {{field.codingGroupField.creatorName}}
            </div>
            <div>{{field.codingGroupField.createdOn | date: 'medium' }}</div>
            <actions-menu [actions]="" [actionOn]=""></actions-menu>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.fields-list-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 1rem;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: move;

        .fields-name-desc-icon {
            display: flex;

            div {
                margin-left: .5rem;
            }

            div:nth-child(2) {
                font-size: 10px;
            }
        }

        .fa-tag {
            color: var(--rational-dark-blue);
        }
    }

    .cdk-drag-placeholder {
        opacity: 0;
    }
.cdk-drag-preview {
    @extend .fields-list-container;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
    transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.draggable-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .fields-list-container:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
    transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

Anyone have any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Can you check if the css rules apply, when you put them in the global styles.css file of your angular project?

Comment: I have the same problem and moving the styless to the global styles.css doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone stumbling upon this issue, it might be due to *where* you've put your `.cdk-drag-preview` styles. Elements being dragged are temporarily moved to the bottom of the html `body`. If the style for this element **isn't** scoped to direct children of the `body`, the style might not apply.

#### Fix

To quickly identify if this is the issue, try moving your drag-related styles to the global styles.css/styles.scss file (as mentioned in the comments by @c-eggart). Or if your drag-related styles are nested, it might be enough to *un-nest* it:

**From:**

```css
.parent {
  .cdk-drag-preview {
    /* some styles */
  }
  /* more drag-related styles */
}
```

**To:**

```css
.parent {

}

.cdk-drag-preview {
  /* some styles */
}
/* more drag-related styles */
```

For more information, see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13288).

Answer (score 1):

Isak's answer is correct and the simplest approach, but if you're unable to rearrange the styles for some reason, there are a couple of alternative solutions I'm aware of:

1. **Change where the preview element is inserted**: use the `cdkDragPreview` directive ([docs link](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#drag-preview-insertion-point)) to change the insertion point from the `<body>` (the default) to either the parent element or a specific `ElementRef` / `HTMLElement`
2. **Specify a different preview element**: use the `*cdkDragPlaceholder` structural directive ([docs link](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#customizing-the-drag-placeholder)) on an element nested inside your `cdkDrag` element to specify a custom preview element/component. It may be worth creating a separate component for this if it's a complicated element

Answer (score -1):

Applying styles as follows works for me

```
.cdk-drag-preview {
  &.fields-list-container {
    // Apply custom styles you want to have 
  }
}
```